# may i use gdata for mobile calendar

Tags: android, calendar

i want to add, delete, update mobile Calendar events. may i use gdata for it. if yes then my code is

```
public void start() {
        try {
            CalendarService calService = new CalendarService("MyCalendarInter");\\ Line no 1
            CalendarFeed resultFeed = calService.getFeed(new URL("content://calendar/calendars"),
                CalendarFeed.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

i am using gdata 1.41.1
and google android api level 3

exception in line number 1 is

java.lang.VerifyError: com.google.gdata.client.Service

reason of using gdata is
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713652/android-problem-deleting-event-in-calender

Comment: i have remove the following exception by adding gdata eclipse plugins.
java.lang.VerifyError: com.google.gdata.client.Service
But still problem in the following line
CalendarFeed resultFeed = calService.getFeed(new URL("content://calendar/calendars"), 
                CalendarFeed.class); 
i think add, delete, update mobile Calendar events is not possible with gdata. Becuase we are not able to convert the Uri to URL.

please give me any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

till now gdata not supported on android.
http://code.google.com/p/android-gdata/

no g data libraries available.

Answer (score 0):

you can you use GoogleApiJavaClient
see here why :
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/MigratingToGoogleApiJavaClient

look here for more resource
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/